# Inaccurate attribute values using joins attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins, excel

I have a shapefile data that represent the location (polygons) and a tabular data represent its detail information. I want to merge the tabular data to the shapefile. I use QGIS 3.22.12

Here are the data (just example):

[image: this is the tabular data]

[image: and this the shapefile]

I imported the .CSV and became a layer. Then I merged it to shapefile layer (properties > joins > Add New Join). When I had done set the joins, I clicked OK.

[image: Add New Vector Join]

And resulting in inaccurate values in the attribute table.
For instance, the five first Konno (I abbreviate it from kon number) coloumn with "DESA" GUNUNGSARI supposed to be kon1, kon2, kon3, kon4, kon5.

If you compare with the original file (.CSV), the shapefile attribute table have different values.
How I could solve this obstacle?

[image: Comparison the attribute table and its original values]

Comment: You need to have a unique field in the attribute table and CSV. Otherwise, any possible result is unreliable.